# What does the notation $A^{-2}$ mean if $A$ is a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, exponentiation, inverse

$A^2$ means to multiple the matrix by itself, and $A^{-1}$ refers to the matrix's inverse. Would $A^{-2}$ be the square of the inverse or the inverse of the square?

Answer (score 7):

It means $(A^{-1})^2$, so the square of the inverse, which also happens to be the inverse of the square.

Comment: which also happens to be the inverse of the square!

Comment: The expression has a conventional meaning only if $A$ is an invertible matrix  (a square matrix of full rank).

Comment: Thank you! Also wow @KennyWong I actually tested that and found that it doesn't, but looking back I was incorrect haha. Would you be able to tell me why exactly this rule works? Do exponent laws apply to matrices?

Answer (score 4):

$$\left(A^{-1}\right)^2A^2=\left(A^{-1}A^{-1}\right)(AA) = A^{-1}\left(A^{-1}A\right)A=A^{-1}IA=A^{-1}A=I
$$
which says that $$\left(A^{-1}\right)^2=\left(A^2\right)^{-1}
$$
This is essentially the same as the proof that $$\left({1\over x}\right)^2={1\over x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown, via induction, that $(A^{-1})^n=(A^n)^{-1}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, whenever $A$ is invertible, $A^{-n}:= (A^{-1})^n=(A^n)^{-1}$.